# C# Audio - How to time stretch (different tempo, same pitch)

Tags: c#, audio, pitch, tempo

I'm trying to make a winform app in C# (VS2008) that can load an mp3 (other formats would be nice, but mp3 at a minimum) and be able to adjust the playback speed (tempo) without affecting pitch.  I really don't need any other audio effects.  I tried using DirectShow but that doesn't seem to offer time stretch capabilities.  I was able to incorporate [irrklang](http://www.ambiera.com/irrklang/) but that does not seem to have the time stretch capability either.  So now I've moved on to [SoundTouch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/).  That certainly has the capabilities but I'm very unclear on how to implement in C#.

After a few days of this, about all I've accomplished is using DLLImport on the SoundTouch DLL and am able to successfully retrieve a version number. At this point, I'm not even sure if I can do what I'm trying to do with SoundTouch.  Can anyone offer some guidance either on how to implement SoundTouch or a different library with the capabilities that I'm looking for?  Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If anyone is still interested, I have written .Net wrapper class for SoundTouch library.
http://code.google.com/p/soundtouchnet/

Answer (score 6):

The answer is that SoundTouch can do what you want to do.

Take a look at the example program [SoundStretch](http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/soundstretch.html). It gives examples of using the SoundTouch library to change the tempo(without changing the pitch) as well as changing the pitch (without changing tempo) and playback rate(change both pitch and tempo). I would look through the source code and use what you need.

The only problem that I see is that you are using an mp3 format and this uses a WAV format so you will need to convert the file first. I really don't think that you'll find a program that does what you want directly on any sort of compressed file because of the nature of the method used to do this sort of thing. It uses a [phase vocoder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_vocoder) if you want to look into the whole process a bit more.

Comment: Was writing a comment basically saying the same thing.  You beat me to it ;)

Comment: That happens to me all the time.

Comment: Ok, well at least I know I'm going down the right avenue.  My problem now is that the examples that I see (and I certainly may be missing something important) are all in C++.  Using DLLImport, I can get this to work in C#:

    SOUNDTOUCHDLL_API const char *__stdcall soundtouch_getVersionString();

For my purposes, I would need to be able to call:

    SOUNDTOUCHDLL_API HANDLE __stdcall soundtouch_createInstance();

And 

    SOUNDTOUCHDLL_API void __stdcall soundtouch_setTempoChange(HANDLE h, float newTempo);

And that is where I'm completely stuck now.

Comment: @heath: Don't write your new problem into a comment. Edit this question and add your ongoing investigation (or problems) at the end or open up a new question. Otherwise nobody will see that you stuck on the next place.

Answer (score 4):

Another way of using SoundTouch in C# is to use the BASS sound library (http://un4seen.com) with the BASS.NET wrapper and the BASS_FX plugin. BASS_FX uses SoundTouch to do TimeStretching.

Answer (score -1):

Here is one possible approach to invoke from C#. You need to write a COM wrapper in C++ to wrap around the SoundTouch DLL. Once you have the COM wrapper ready, you can import it into your .NET (C#) project and invoke the underlying SoundTouch DLL through the COM Wrapper. Hope this helps.